Is there a way to group data by value in one column to produce a sum of contents in other column in pandas?
I'm sorry if this is a repeat, I can't find anything that gives me an answer...
I have a dataframe containing pixel values and the number of pixels of that value. It looks something like this:
Value    Count 
0.1457   900  
0.1458   1800
0.1459   900
0.2144   1800  
0.4357   2700
0.5764   900
0.7891   1800
0.7892   900
nan      0
nan      0

In this case each instance of nan indicates a single pixel with no data.
I'd like to group these values into 4 classes as follows...:

Low:     <0.2
Mid:     0.2 - 0.6
High:    >0.6
No Data: nan

...and then produce a sum for each class, like so using the above example data:
Class    Count
Lo       3600
Mid      6300
Hi       2700
ND       2

I appreciate there are likely to be several steps to this, but does anyone have any pointers?

Examples are needed for reproduction purposes, not only for reference. Please provide input that is complete without omissions and provide the desired output that can be generated from your input. Your question is not a difficult one, so follow these steps and it should be easy to answer.

Thank you, I understand. In this case my data is more than 15000 rows so I wanted provide a condensed but representative version. Would you suggest attaching a copy of the file via, for example, a file transfer site instead? Or does how I have edited the above suffice?

read notice : [mre]. You can create a minimal, reproducible example that represents the logic you need. No one will download your files.

Ok thanks I think my example is now appropriate

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Value":[i*0.01 for i in range(1000)]+[np.nan,np.nan],"Count ":list(range(1000))+[np.nan,1]})
df['Class'] = ["Lo" if v < 0.2 else "Mid" if v > 0.2 and v < 0.6 else "ND" if np.isnan(v) else "Hi" for v in df.Value]

df.groupby(['Class']).sum()

Output:



Class
Value
Count




Hi
4977.5
497750


Lo
1.9
190


Mid
15.6
1560


ND
0
1




This is handy... can you include a count for the NaN values too?

Nice one, thanks, this has worked

You can use cut to form the bins, mask the 0s where there are NaNs, and groupby.sum (with dropna=False):
out = (df['Count'].mask(df['Value'].isna(), 1)
       .groupby(pd.cut(df['Value'], bins=[-np.inf, 0.2, 0.6, np.inf],
                       labels=['Low', 'Mid', 'High']),
                dropna=False)
       .sum()
      )

Output:
Value
Low     3600
Mid     5400
High    2700
NaN        2
Name: Count, dtype: int64

Intermediates before aggregation:
   masked Count   cut
0           900   Low
1          1800   Low
2           900   Low
3          1800   Mid
4          2700   Mid
5           900   Mid
6          1800  High
7           900  High
8             1   NaN
9             1   NaN


You can create a new Series object with the Low, Mid, High, NoData labels, then pass the Series to groupby method.
s = pd.Series('', index=df.index)
s[df.Value.lt(0.2)] = 'Low'
s[df.Value.ge(0.2) & df.Value.lt(0.6)] = 'Mid'
s[df.Value.ge(0.6)] = 'High'
s[df.Value.isna()] = 'NoData'

counts = df['Count'].groupby(s).sum()
counts['NoData'] = s.value_counts()['NoData']

counts
# returns:
High      2700
Low       3600
Mid       5400
NoData       2
Name: Count, dtype: int64


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Value': [0.1457, 0.1458, 0.1459, 0.2144, 0.4357, 0.5764, 0.7891, 0.7892, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Count': [900, 1800, 900, 1800, 2700, 900, 1800, 900, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate NaN count before modifying DataFrame
no_data_count = df['Value'].isna().sum()

conditions = [(df['Value'] < 0.2),(df['Value'] >= 0.2) & (df['Value'] <= 0.6),(df['Value'] > 0.6)]
conditions_name = ['Low','Mid','Hi']
df = df.assign(
Class = np.select(
conditions,conditions_name, default = 'ND'
)).groupby('Class')['Count'].sum().reset_index()

print(df)
'''
  Class  Count
0    Hi   2700
1   Low   3600
2   Mid   5400
3    ND      0
'''
df.loc[df['Class'] == 'ND','Count'] = no_data_count
print(df)
'''
  Class  Count
0    Hi   2700
1   Low   3600
2   Mid   5400
3    ND      2
'''

